# How to print a new line in C++ using vectors?

Tags: c++

I want to print a new line after printing out certain indexes [0], v[2], v[6], v[14]. increments of 2^(n+1)

```
for (int i = 0; i < v2.size(); i++)
{   
    std::cout << v2[i] << " ";
    // need to print a new line after done printing v[0], v[2], v[6], v[14] 
}
```

I tried hard coding `if(i== 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || .. || i == 30)` but that seems not so efficient. Any suggestions?

Comment: How often do you want new lines printed out? Your question is inconsistent.

Comment: `2^n+1` and the sequence `([0], [2], [6], [14])` is inconsistent.

Comment: consider this sequence: 0 2 4 6 14 and so on
f(n) = 2^(n+1) - 2

Comment: The program's text says 0,2,6,14 and the question says 0,2,4,...30. Which one is it?

Comment: that depends on the v2.size(). it can go on and on depending how large is the vector.

Comment: Shouldn't the loop start at `int i = 0` if you want to print the `v2[0]` element?

Comment: @Nawaz, it's *increments* of 2(n+1) : 2+4+8 = 14, 2+4+8+16=30. Made my head spin at first, too.

Comment: I think you mean `i == 14` instead of `i == 4`???

Comment: Please pick a better title for this question, the actual problem is about loops and has _nothing_ to do with vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    if ((i & (i+1)) == 0) // print newline if i+1 is a power of two
```

Comment: OP wants `i+2` to be a power of two, so you're off by one.

Comment: @us2012 : It's confusing. He says he wants a newline after v[0], but his for loop starts at v[1]. For now this is as close as I'm prepared to go. Fixing an off-by-one should be trivial.

Comment: Ah, their code is indeed confusing. Well then, +1 for the first correct answer to this question.

Comment: Bleh. The question was ambiguous to begin with.
(0, 2, 6, 14), 2^n+1, and (i == 0 || i == 2 || i == 4 || ... || i == 30) are 3 completely different things...

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Indeed. Welcome psychics.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, try this:

```
unsigned uNext = 0, power = 0;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < v2.size(); ++i) {
  cout << v2[i] << (i == uNext) ? endl : " ");
  uNext = (uNext == i) ? uNext + pow(2, ++power): uNext;
}
```

You have to check that you do not overflow the unsigned uNext so add some checks.

Comment: Again, where do you get the `pow` for integers? It's not in `<cmath>` for sure.

Comment: @us2012 pow as of C++11 does have it for integers, iirc.

Comment: Even if you cannot use that version it is fairly easy to implement one on your own.

Comment: @Rapptz Sure? Not even cppreference knows about it, and they're quite up to date.

Comment: @us2012 `Promoted pow( Arithmetic base, Arithmetic exp );` promotes it to a double.

Comment: `pow()`?? Pass me the sledgehammer, I have peanut here.

Comment: @Rapptz That should mean that it's only safe if your integral type has fewer bits than the mantissa of `double`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing Roddy is right, and in fact, you want the length of
each line to increase to the next power of two, the problem is
easily solved using a variation on the standard idiom:

```
int maxInLineCount = 2;
int inLineCount = 0;
for ( auto current = v.begin(); current != v.end(); ++ current ) {
    if ( inLineCount != 0 ) {
        std::cout << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << *current;
    ++ inLineCount;
    if ( inLineCount >= maxInLineCount ) {
        std::cout << '\n';
        inLineCount = 0;
        maxInLineCount *= 2;    //  This is the added bit.
    }
}
if ( inLineCount != 0 ) {
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```